# Handling Dates in FTP

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, ftp

Here is my ftp script

```
#!/bin/sh
FTPHOST='dedibackup-dc2.xx.net'
FTPUSER='sd-xxxxx'
FTPPASSWD='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

ftp -n -v $FTPHOST << EOT
ascii
user $FTPUSER $FTPPASSWD
prompt

now=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
echo $now
bye
EOT
```

The output of this script is:

```
Trying 62.210.XX.XX...
Connected to dedibackup-dc2.XXXX.net (62.210.XX.XX).
220 server ready - login please
530 login first
331 password required
230 login accepted
Interactive mode off.
?Invalid command
?Invalid command
221 goodbye
```

I googled and seen some posts regarding dates but all provided formats not worked for me.

Please advise

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: You can't use bash commands in FTP

Comment: @123 is there any other way to accomplish it?

Comment: @123 `!echo $now` worked. How you said bash commands are not working in FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

through to FTP, which can include executing commands, substituting variables, and the like.  That is to say, instead of writing:

**ftp < ftp_args>  << EOT

blah

bloho $VAR1

bleeeoogah $(some cmd)

EOT**

just do this:

**( echo blah; echo bloho $VAR1; echo bleeeoogah $(some_cmd) ) | ftp**